# Changing processes priority in linux

Tags: linux, operating-system, system-calls

I have a C code, that generates two processes, but I want to change their priority in kernel, so I wrote a `syscall`, in which, increasing and decreasing the priority of two processes (I tried this with all types of priorities, `static_prio`, `normal_prio`, `prio`, `rt_priority`) but again the processes ran simultaneously!

I can't  use other syscalls in my `syscall` code and the operating system is ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.4.

Comment: *Guessing*: depending on the overall workload of your system, there might simply be enough resources for both of your processes. If possible, you could try to put some real load on your system, to then see if the process with higher priority does better in that situation.

Comment: You want one process to complete before the other is scheduled at all?

Comment: @GhostCat, I tried using VM and only one core but it didn't work

Comment: yeah, @thatotherguy, something like that

Comment: If your CPU is idleing most of the time, then that doesn't matter. But when you really want to trigger processes **in sequence** then you are working on the wrong thing. Then you just **trigger** them in sequence; and you do not worry about priorities. If your processes run **after** each other, then their priorities do not matter at all!

Comment: @GhostCat , the challenge is here, two processes at the same time start running, (using fork to run two process as children) and I must change the order of execution by changing priorities (and probably some other works)!

Comment: @Mehdi And you are sure that things wouldnt be easier if those two processes would know about each other and sync up directly? Or some kind of "command server" architecture where those processes talk to their parent ... and get instructions from there?

Comment: Priority is not used to control order of execution. It's used to control which process is preferred when there aren't enough resources to run both of them. But if your computer has multiple CPUs, as most do these days, it may be able to run them both concurrently. And even if you only have one CPU, if a process needs to wait for data from disk, network, or the user, the other process will be allowed to run while it's waiting.

Answer (score 0):

- First, about concurrency: With sufficient resources, a single processor can be "working on" more than one program at the same time. The processor can not be executing instructions from several programs simultaneously (it can only execute one instruction at any time), but it may be executing instructions from one program after it has started another program and before it has finished that other program. These programs are said to be executing "concurrently". Typically, the processor will be executing instructions for one program while another (or several other) program(s) are waiting for I/O from external devices or from an end-user.
- Second, Efficiency: scheduler should keep the system (or in particular CPU) busy 100% percent of the time when possible. If the CPU and all the Input/Output devices can be kept running all the time, more work gets done per second than if some components are idle. If we assume that you have a Dual-core processor, Then, the scheduler will assign your two processes each to one processor of the dual processors (as a minimum you need more processes than number of processors).
- Third, you must put a huge load on your system to start seeing results of your code as priority scheduling used to schedule processes when there is limited resources on the machine to prevent deadlocks from happen. So, if you have Dual-core processor you need about three or more processes to start seeing results and so on (as we mentioned above about efficiency).